# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when date is left blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm currently creating a website using MEAN stack, and I'm almost done, but there's a problem with the "user editing his/her profile" part. When the user edits anything ALONG WITH editing his/her birthdate, the edit works just fine and all is updated in the database, however when the birthdate field is left empty I get the following error in node:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "birthdate"

Here's my nodejs code:

```
exports.editInformation = function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.userID;
        var body = req.body;

        User.findOne({_id:id}, function(err, user) {
            if(err)  
                res.send("error");
            else {
                if(!user) 
                    res.send("user not found");
                else {    
                    if(body.name) 
                        user.name = body.name;

                    if(body.birthdate)
                        user.birthdate = new Date(body.birthdate);

                    if(typeof body.phone != "undefined" && body.phone.length > 0) 
                        user.phone = body.phone;

                    if(typeof body.gender != "undefined" && body.gender.length > 0) 
                        user.gender = body.gender;

                    if(typeof body.address != "undefined" && body.address.length > 0) 
                        user.address = body.address;

                    if(typeof body.email != "undefined" && body.email.length > 0) 
                        user.email = body.email;

                    if(typeof file != "undefined") 
                        user.profilePic = file.filename;

                    user.save();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message states the reason:

> ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "birthdate"

It suggests `body.birthdate` evaluates to `true` (perhaps it contains a space or something?), but `new Date(body.birthdate)` yields an invalid date.

Because you're not handling *any* errors thrown by `user.save()`, you get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. You're also not sending back any response either.

So there's two issues that you should fix: after calling `new Date(body.birthdate)`, you should check if the date is actually valid:

```
if (body.birthdate) {
  user.birthdate = new Date(body.birthdate);
  if ( isNaN( user.birthdate.getTime() ) ) {
    return res.send('error'); // or whatever response you deem appropriate
  }
}
```

And also, you should handle errors thrown by `save` and act accordingly:

```
user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) return res.send('error');
  res.send('okay');
});
```

Comment: alright now the errors don't show in the console, however, this still didn't solve the problem. That is if the user edited his/ name, without changing the birthdate (leaving it as previewed by the html), the user's info (in this case name) doesn't get updated in the database.

Comment: So what does `body.birthdate` contain, exactly? And is it something that you can pass into `new Date()` (that is, is it a format that the `Date` constructor accepts)?

Comment: When I don't enter anything in the edit birthdate field, when I console.log the following: console.log("Birthdate in body: " + body.birthdate); .. this shows up in the console: Birthdate in body: null @robertklep

Comment: My guess is that it's a string containing the word `null`, which will cause the created date to be invalid. You need to validate your input, or filter away those strings (`if (body.birthdate && body.birthdate !== 'null') { ... }`).